# What is the connection between the valuation of a polynomial of a function filed of a curve and the corresponding laurent series?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, valuation-theory

I've read somewhere an MSE that we can understand the normalized valuation of a polynomial in the function field of a curve at a smooth point as the first non-vanishing coefficient (or exponent) of a corresponding laurent series, meaning that (using Silvermans notation) for the function $f \in \overline{K}(C)$ it's sufficient to get find a local parametrization g of C in a neighborhood of P with $g(0) = P, g'(0) \neq 0$. Then if $$f(g(t)) = \sum_{i \geq n} a_i t^i$$ with $a_n \neq 0$ then $\text{ord}_P(f) = a_n$ (or just the exponent n?).

The poster then argued that $t \mapsto (x(t),t^2)$ is a parametrization of $y^2 = x^3 + x$ with $x(t) = t - t^3+3t^5-12t^7+O(t^9)$ being the inverse series of $x^3+x$ and with this $\text{ord}_P(y) = 1$.

But I don't understand this argument at all. Why use the inverse series? Why is this indeed a parametrization? How exactly can I now get the order? Can I also conclude now a statement about the order of x?

I just can't find the post for the life of me and almost forgot about it until I read in the MIT course notes on elliptic curves:

This is clear when $k = \mathbb{C}$ and in general one can formally define the Laurent series
expansion g ∈ k((t)) of f at P so that $\text{ord}_P(f)$ is the exponent of its leading term.

So there is indeed a connection but it's quite difficult for me to grasp it and use it to find seeked orders.

Edit: Found the link ([What does the power of an ideal *mean*?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225386/what-does-the-power-of-an-ideal-mean)), but I think there has to be a mistake since he actually argues that $$\text{ord}_P(x) = 1$$, which cant be the case since $$\text{ord}_P(x) = \text{ord}_P(y^2-x^3) = \min\{\text{ord}_P(y^2),\text{ord}_P(x^3)\} = 2$$

Comment: 1. Please add the link to the post in your post. 2. While you're editing that in, you have a number of mismatched dollar signs and instances math outside of MathJax which you could improve, too.

Comment: The answer in the post you linked has it exactly backwards. $x$ vanishes to order $2$ at $(0,0)$, and $y$ vanishes to order $1$. The tangent line at $(0,0)$ is $x = 0$, as can be seen from the fact that the lowest order term of the Taylor series centered at $(0,0)$ of the defining polynomial $x - y^2 + x^3$ is $x$. I don't see exactly where their mistake is, but I'm suspicious of the purported local parametrization they gave.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Is there an easy explanation why the order (defined with ideals) correspond to the terms in the taylor series?

Comment: @Zedssad For simplicity, let's assume that $k$ is algebraically closed. Given a smooth point $P$, consider the local ring $k[C]_P$ at $P$ with unique maximal ideal $m$; let $t$ be a uniformizer, so $m = (t)$. We can complete this ring with respect to $m$ to obtain the complete local ring $\widehat{k[C]_P}$. It's a theorem that $\widehat{k[C]_P} \cong k[[t]]$, the power series ring in $t$ (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/191725)). We have a ring morphism $k[C]_P \to \widehat{k[C]_P} \cong k[[t]]$, which basically amounts to writing a function $f$ regular at $P$ as a power series...

Comment: ...in the uniformizer $t$. Note that, for both $k[C]_P$ and $k[[t]]$, all of their ideals are of the form $(t^v)$ for some $v \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, and the map $k[C]_P \to k[[t]]$ takes $t^v$ to $t^v$, so it preserves valuations. And given a series $a_v t^v + a_{v+1} t^{v+1} + \cdots$ with $a_v \neq 0$, since $a_v t^v + a_{v+1} t^{v+1} \cdots = t^v\left(a_v + a_{v+1} t  +  \cdots\right)$, and $a_v + a_{v+1} t  +  \cdots$ doesn’t vanish at $t=0$, then its order of vanishing is $v$. For an example, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4063565) of mine.